# Unable to print text from website using python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

As it give me error an on brand only  how should i resolved it

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:/python/davago.py", line 15, in 
brand= property.find('h3', class_ = 'productitem--vendor').text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import *
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://dvago.pk/collections/cardio-vascular-system?page=1&grid_list=grid-view'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'productitem')
#print(content)
for property in content:
    names= property.find('div', class_ = 'productitem--info')
    name= names.find('h2', class_ = 'productitem--title').text.strip()
    brand= property.find('h3', class_ = 'productitem--vendor').text.strip()
    

    print(name,brand)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should find 'productgrid--items' first then you go over each item in there.
There is probably another use for the 'productitem' class but without the h3 in it and that's why you are getting the exception :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import *
# import pandas as pd
# import time

url = 'https://dvago.pk/collections/cardio-vascular-system?page=1&grid_list=grid-view'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
aaa = soup.find('div', class_='productgrid--items') ## <------
content = aaa.find_all('div', class_='productitem') ## <------
# print(content)
for property in content:
    names = property.find('div', class_='productitem--info')
    name = names.find('h2', class_='productitem--title').text.strip()
    brand = property.find('h3', class_='productitem--vendor').text.strip()

    print(name, brand)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you see last three content does not have vendor name so you can use `try` and `except` block to handle `exception` and print appropraite statement

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import *
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://dvago.pk/collections/cardio-vascular-system?page=1&grid_list=grid-view'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'productitem')
#print(content)
for property in content:
    names= property.find('div', class_ = 'productitem--info')
    try:
        name= names.find('h2', class_ = 'productitem--title').text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        name="Company name not available"
    try:
        brand= property.find('h3', class_ = 'productitem--vendor').text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        brand="Brand name not available"
    

    print("Company Name:",name)
    print("Brand Name:",brand)
```